# Discontinuity (Limits)

Tags: calculus

Why is the following function discontinuous at x=1?

Would my approach be to graph this equation or solve for the limit? I'm not sure how to start this problem. I understand continuity but I'm unsure about discontinuity. 
The function is a piecewise

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2-x}{x^2-1} & x \neq 1 \\
2 & x=1     
\end{cases}$$

(a) $f(1)$ does not exist.

(b) $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)$ does not exist (or is infinite).

(c) Both (a) and (b).

(d) $f(1)$ and $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)$ exist, they are not equal.

Comment: So if I understood correctly the limit as x-->1 does exist but since the value resulted in 1/2, the results are not equal. I see my mistake as I was trying to plug in 1 into my function, therefore my answer choice would be d ? Thank you so much for helping me understand this problem

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$ if 
$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)
$$
In terms of your question, we want to check the continuity (or lack thereof) of $f$ at $x=1$. This amounts to checking whether or not
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = f(1)
$$
Because of how $f$ is defined, we already know $f(1)=2$. What is $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$?

When we take limits, remember that we're not actually plugging in the point to which we're taking a limit. In this case, we can't just go ahead and plug 1 in for $x$. Instead, we're actually approaching 1 from both sides. This means that we're working with $f$ when $x \neq 1$. Hence,
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^2-x}{x^2-1} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+1)} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x}{x+1} 
$$
Since both $\lim_{x \to 1} (x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 1} (x+1)$ exist, we use our limit laws to obtain
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \frac{\lim_{x \to 1} x}{\lim_{x \to 1} x+1} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
But $\frac{1}{2} \neq 2$, so we've contradicted the condition that we need for continuity. Therefore, $f$ is discontinuous at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2-x}{x^2-1}=\frac{x(x-1)}{(x+1)(x-1)}=\frac{x}{x+1}$$
Let $\epsilon>0$.  Then

$$f(1-\epsilon)=\frac{1-\epsilon}{1-\epsilon+1}=\frac{1-\epsilon}{2-\epsilon}$$
$$f(1+\epsilon)=\frac{1+\epsilon}{1+\epsilon+1}=\frac{1+\epsilon}{2+\epsilon}$$

Thus, as we approach $x=1$ from the left or right, we are approaching a value of $1/2$, but by definition, $f(1)=2$ so you can see the discontinuity as we approach $x=1$ from the left and right.  For continuity to hold, you also need the limit to approach the actual value of $f(1)$, but this is not the case.  Thus we are discontinuous at $x=1$.

Comment: Yes, the limit exists as x approaches 1, but for continuity to hold, as @Petaro mentioned in his answer, you need the condition that the limit actually equals the value at $f(1)$, which we know doesn't hold, since the limit approaches $1/2$, but $f(1)=2$